# Emacs mode integration with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, emacs, elisp

I find myself editing documents with both HTML and JS frequently. One thing that is slightly aggravating is the integration between javascript-mode and html-mode and the indentation / integration between the modes.

Just curious if anybody can point me to the solution for this workflow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [web-mode](http://web-mode.org/)?

> `web-mode.el` is an autonomous emacs major-mode for editing web
>   templates: HTML documents embedding parts (CSS / JavaScript) and
>   blocks (client / server side)

Additional possibilities are listed on the [Emacs wiki Multiple Modes page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes):

- polymode
- web-mode.el
- mmm-mode.el
- multi-web-mode.el
- mumamo.el
- multi-mode.el
- two-mode-mode.el
- Indirect buffers